# Color map or SLD for Global Wind Atlas?

Tags: color-ramp

I am trying to use the Global Wind Atlas for a map about alternative energy:

https://globalwindatlas.info

I have downloaded the 14.5GB geotiff of global wind power density. QGIS reads it perfectly and I can apply a color ramp, but I would like to match the existing product exactly. Does anyone know where to obtain a color map or SLD file? Or how to extract the styling information from the online resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind manually picking colors from the legend color bar;

1. In the `Layer Properties` panel > `Symbology` tab, choose `Singleband pseudocolor` to render the color.
2. Select `Discrete` for the Interpolation settings.
3. Double-click on the Color to activate `Select color` dialogue window.
4. Click on `Sample color` button on the color picker tab.
5. Go to Global Wind Atlas map and click on the legend to pick the color.
6. Go back to the `Layer Properties` panel then you will find the color has been updated. Double-click on the value next to the color and set the value according to the legend.
7. Repeat the above color-picking process (31 colors)... ...

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Both these answers are spot on and the quality of detail really nicely done.

Answer (score 5):

You can read the actual R,G,B colours and values from the web-page source code:

[image]

Here they are as text, you could (manually) use this to set the symbology in QGIS:

```
R, G, B, Value
153, 51, 102, >1300
165, 47, 90, 1300
176, 43, 77, 1200
188, 39, 65, 1100
199, 35, 52, 1000
211, 31, 40, 900
226, 63, 40, 850
232, 78, 41, 800
238, 92, 41, 750
245, 106, 41, 700
246, 137, 53, 650
247, 160, 63, 600
248, 184, 73, 550
249, 208, 82, 500
250, 232, 92, 450
212, 221, 87, 400
178, 211, 83, 375
145, 202, 79, 350
111, 192, 75, 325
73, 181, 70, 300
73, 173, 99, 275
73, 165, 124, 250
72, 158, 148, 225
72, 150, 173, 200
72, 142, 202, 175
90, 158, 212, 150
106, 173, 220, 125
123, 187, 229, 100
141, 204, 238, 75
178, 226, 249, 50
197, 233, 250, <25
```